# Python. Не могу получить нормальный ответ от xu.su

Tags: python, requests

xu.su - это что то вроде бота, который может говорить с человеком, я хочу получать его ответ
Я узнал что у них есть "скрытый апи" - xu.su/api/send
И вместо того что бы получить нормальный ответ, выходит что то вроде "Ой, напиши ещё раз", но не ответ по смыслу.
Снизу код

```
response = requests.post('https://xu.su/api/send/', data = {'bot': 'main', 'text': 'input text', 'uid': None})
if response.status_code == 200:
    answer_json = response.json()
                       
    print(answer_json['text'])
else:
    pass
```

Comment: Может быть нужно добавить Headers?

Comment: Вроде uid - null, то есть None

Comment: Не знаю, как он должен работать, но у меня вроде все работает, только что проверил. Код такой: `resp = requests.post(url, data = data)`, `url = 'https://xu.su/api/send/', data = {'bot': 'main', 'text': 'input text', 'uid': None}`. Вот только я поле `Text` поменял на сообщение, которое хотел отослать.
Типа `data['text'] = 'Привет'`.

Comment: Может кодировка у текста не та, которую он понимает? )  Я бы Fiddler-ом посмотрел какие запросы уходят от браузера и от скрипта и сравнил

Answer (score 0):

сам работал с api xusu когда писал своего бота для тг, у меня все работает. Вот мой код:

```
r = requests.post('https://xu.su/api/send', {"uid":'',"bot":'main',"text":'input_text'}) #отправляем post запрос
text = r.text #ответ закидываем в переменную
text = text.replace('true', 'True') #заменяем "true" на "True" (нужно для следующей строки, тк не дает превратить в словарь)
data = eval(text) #превращаем ответ в словарь
print(data[text]) #выводим текст ответа в консоль
```

ps. возможно можно сделать лучше, но мне было лень)

Comment: Зачем такие сложности с заменой и `eval`, там же готовый `json`. Просто берёте `json` прямо из ответа: `print(r.json()['text'])`